# How to resolve "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

How to resolve "NoClassDefFoundError" which is occuring while running the Appium script.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no javax.websocket.DeploymentException class in your classpath. You should add it to your app dependencies. Depending on what dependency manager you use there would be different steps. Here you can find:

- [Client websocket libs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-client-api/1.1)
- [Server websocket libs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.1)

With the definitions you should add to the most popular dependency managers config.